# interesting multistep forms in django

Tags: django, forms, postback, inorder, multi-step

I have a multi-step form but it is a little different from commons. The difference is not all steps are consecutive and forms may be inorder. To be clear, let say there are
`Form1` , `Form2` , `Form3` and `Form4`.

Those may run like `Form1` - `Form2` - `Form3` or `Form1` - `Form2` - `Form4`. However, there is no chance like `Form2` - `Form1` (Form_x - form_y | x < y)

How can I implement such form chains in django ?
Also, I couldn't understand how FormWizard works. Does it produce back button automatically or how does it behave when user turns to previous form ? Could explain or give simple example or refernce ?

Thanks

Comment: All forms are linked to the same model or each form is linked to a distinct model?

Comment: First two are linked to the same model but others linked to the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FormWizard will not provide back nor submit buttons, this is up to your template.

FormWizard is just a fancy view that will handle the template rendering and pass the data around forms until completion.